# Using list comprehension for fraction results in a function

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to write  function that prints out float fractions of % of positive numbers, negative numbers and numbers that = 0, based on values passed in through `*args`.  I figured list comprehension would be an efficient way to get those values, but the following is not working.  I am getting an 'int' object is not iterable error message.  Any ideas?

```
def plusMinus(*args):
    list_1 = []
    count = 0
    for i in args:
        list_1.append(i)
        count += 1
    pos = [i % sum(i) for i in list_1 if i > 0]
    neg = [i % sum(i) for i in list_1 if i < 0]
    zero = [i % sum(i) for i in list_1 if i == 0]
    num = count
    print(num)
    print(args)
    print(pos)
    print(neg)
    print(zero)

plusMinus(10, 25, 30, 0, -45, -50)
```

Comment: `sum` expects an iterable object. You are giving it `i` which is an integer. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be an approach:

```
def plusMinus(*args):

    num = len(args)
    pos = sum(1 for i in args if i > 0)
    neg = sum(1 for i in args if i < 0)
    # zero = sum(1 for i in args if i == 0)
    zero = num - pos - neg

    print('pos: {:1.1%}'.format(pos/num))
    print('neg: {:1.1%}'.format(neg/num))
    print('zero: {:1.1%}'.format(zero/num))

plusMinus(10, 25, 30, 0, -45, -50)
```

which outputs:

```
pos: 50.0%
neg: 33.3%
zero: 16.7%
```

note that string formatting can output `float`s as percent.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` takes an iterable as input, so in your list comprehension you are applying it to only one element, should be fixed like this for example:

```
[i % sum(list_1) for i in list_1 if i > 0]
```

**EDIT**

> I want the % numbers for each pos, neg and zero

Your algorithm should be this:

```
def plusMinus(*args):
    size = len(args)
    pos  = len([i for i in args if i > 0])/size
    neg  = len([i for i in args if i < 0])/size
    zero = len([i for i in args if i == 0])/size
    print(pos*100)
    print(neg*100)
    print(zero*100)
```

Comment: thank you.  that worked but I just realized I am not doing this correctly.  That returns 3 lists (as expected) but i want the % numbers for each pos, neg and zero. not lists.  Hmmm.  Ok.  Ill need to dig into this more

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate percentage depending upon the elements

```
>>> pos = sum([1 for i in list_1 if i > 0]) / len(list_1) * 100
50.0
>>> neg = sum([1 for i in list_1 if i < 0]) / len(list_1) * 100
33.33333333333333
>>> zero = sum([1 for i in list_1 if i == 0]) / len(list_1) * 100
16.666666666666664
```